# Is there a GA4 API for Profile List?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

From GA v3, I'm able to list all profiles linked to my master account;

```
Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService.Management.Profiles.List("~all", "~all")
```

And from this, I'm able to read each account;

```
Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService.Data.Ga.Get($"ga:{gav3.Id}"
```

But, since GA it's now GA4, I must have the PropertyId from each child account and I'm having trouble to get the Profiles. From the library `Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta` I couldn't find a way to list all profiles.

So my question, is there a way to list all my child profiles and get all the GA4 properties?

[UPDATE]

I've found this (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/accounts/list), but nothing for NuGet Package.